# How to achieve this reference style using `biblatex`?

Tags: biblatex

So, I've come to the final part of writing my thesis, which is adding these references, however I was not able to replicate the required style set by the university.

This is an example how it should look like:

[image]

However, this is how far I've managed to got:

[image]

For this, I have the following configs:

```
\defbibheading{refheading}[References]{%
  \section*{\normalfont\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont #1}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}

\renewcommand\bibname{References}
```

I've added the Accessed data to the `notes` field:

```
@online{tdd,
    author    = "Anca Onuta",
    title     = "How to Get Started with Test Driven Development — A Step by Step Guide",
    url       = "https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-get-started-with-test-driven-development-a-step-by-step-guide-bfdd831fae71",
    note      = "Accessed 2023-06-16",
}
```

Any help would be recommended, this is kinda nerve wrecking by now. :)

## update

So after I was pointed that i can use the `urldate` prop, that changed things a bit, and now I am fairly close actually.

This is the current macro i am having:

```
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \printtext{\newline}
  \printtext{Accessed \printfield{urldate}\newline}
  \printtext{\printfield{url}}
}
```

And the result is now very close to what I need to do:

[image]

The `urldate` field however is still not being printed, If I want to print it with `printfield`. Plus I need a linebreak between the reference entries.

Comment: `@online` of the standard `biblatex` styles and several third-party styles does already support `urldate`. So you should not need `note` for it.

Comment: oh that is correct actually. so `urldate   = "2023-06-15"` is working. now, the only thing missing is to somehow make the layout which i need. currently the urldate gets added to the entire end of the reference entry in brackets.

Comment: `\printurldate` 'If I want to print it with `\printfield`': you don't ;). See `\bibitemsep` for the vertical spacing.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a weird bibliography style.

Comment: @cfr and thats not the only weird thing at this place.

Answer (score 0):

okay after messing around with it a lot, this is how i've managed to make it *somewhat* what i needed to achieve:

```
\newbibmacro*{myurl+urldate}{%
  \printfield{title}\newline
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\printtext{Accessed \thefield{urlyear}-\thefield{urlmonth}-\thefield{urlday}}\newline}
  \printfield{url}
}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{myurl+urldate}
}
```

And now it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This should have been an edit to the question, but showing additional work is usually welcomed.

Comment: As I said before, there are specific macros for printing different kinds of fields. You should use the more specific ones where applicable.